# How to predict target label using scikit learn

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

Let's say I have a dataset, I will provide a toy example in this instance...

```
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
target = "A"
```

...which generates...

```
        A   B   C   D
    0  75  38  81  58
    1  36  92  80  79
    2  22  40  19  3
       ...    ...
```

This is clearly not enough data to give a good accuracy, but nevertheless, let's say I feed `data` and `target` to a `random forest` algorithm provided by *scikit learn*...

```
def random_forest(target, data):

    # Drop the target label, which we save separately.
    X = data.drop([target], axis=1).values
    y = data[target].values

    # Run Cross Validation on Random Forest Classifier.
    clf_tree = ske.RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=50)
    unique_permutations_cross_val(X, y, clf_tree)
```

`unique_permutations_cross_val` is simply a cross-validation function I made, this is the function (it prints out the accuracy of the model as well)...

```
def unique_permutations_cross_val(X, y, model):

    # Split data 20/80 to be used in a K-Fold Cross Validation with unique permutations.
    shuffle_validator = model_selection.ShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    # Calculate the score of the model after Cross Validation has been applied to it. 
    scores = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=shuffle_validator)

    # Print out the score (mean), as well as the variance.
    print("Accuracy: %0.4f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std()))
```

Anyways, my main question is, how can I predict the target label using this model I created. For example, let's say I feed the model `[28, 12, 33]`. I want the model to predict the `target` which in this case is `"A"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This model in the posted code is not fitted yet. You did cross validation, which will tell you how well (or not) the model is training on your data, but it will not fit the model object as you want. `cross_val_score()` uses clones of the supplied model object to find the scores.

For predicting the data, you need to explicitly call `fit()` on the model.

So maybe you can edit your `random_forest` method to return the fitted model. Something like this:

```
unique_permutations_cross_val(X, y, clf_tree)
clf_tree.fit(X, y)
return clf_tree
```

And then wherever you are calling the `random_forest` method, you can do this:

```
fitted_model = random_forest(target, data)

predictions = fitted_model.predict([data to predict])
```